# Multiplication of matrices using pointer notation in C

Tags: c, pointers

I have some funny issue in here when multiplying two matrices in C

when I use array notation, things go perfectly fine like
declaring
`int m1,m2,n1,n2,a[20][20],b[20][20],c[20][20],i,j,k,term=0;`
then scanning everything and getting every term by

```
for(i=0;i<m1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n2;j++)
        {
            for(k=0;k<n1;k++)
                term +=  a[i][k]  *  b[k][j] ;
                
            c[i][j]=term;
            term=0;
        }
    }
```

this is perfect.

but to use POINTERS ONLY like declaring
 `int m1,m2,n1,n2,*a,*b,*c,i,j,k,term=0;`
then scanning number of rows and columns and then

```
    a=malloc(m1*n1*sizeof(int));
    b=malloc(m2*n2*sizeof(int));
    c=malloc(m1*n2*sizeof(int));
```

then scanning every entry by

```
for(i=0;i<m1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n1;j++)
            scanf("%d",a+i*m1+j);
    }
```

till here things are fine. but to calculate the resultant matrix by

```
for(i=0;i<m1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n2;j++)
        {
            for(k=0;k<n1;k++)
            {
                term += *(a+m1*i+k) * (*(b+k*m2+j));        
            }
            *(c+m1*i+j)=term;
            term=0;
        }
    }
```

things happen well but the last row of the resultant matrix gives incorrect answers!!!

what am I doing wrong?
please help!!

Comment: Please show a [MCVE]

Comment: so should I write the entire code here?

Comment: `scanf("%d",a+i*m1+j);` In every outer loop `i` you did `n1` inner loops with j. So you have to `scanf("%d",a+i*n1+j);`

Comment: so the question is how to convert  term +=  a[i][k]  *  b[k][j] ;.......to pinter notation assuming only int *a,*b,*c have been declared

Comment: BTW: when you make a minimal example out of your code, the chances are high you find the problem yourself.

Comment: Your last comment is the question.

Comment: There's a very useful rule of thumb for multidimensional index calculations. If you have both `i<N` and `i*N` in the same loop, one of them is wrong. (Unless you know your matrix is square).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `m1` rows of `n1` elements. So to address `a[i][j]`, the calculation should be `a+i*n1+j`, that is, "skip `i` rows `n1` elements, then take the `j`th element of that row.

Comment: but since I have declared     a=malloc(m1*n1*sizeof(int));    which means m1 *n1 "consecutive locations" are reserved. so scanning elements row-wise should be a+i*m1+j (rows run from 0 to m1 minus 1) so when m1=0 (first loop) we scan at the a+j location. this scans elements of the first row. then i becomes 1 and we go to scan at the a+m1+j th locations....isn't that right? it is like each row is placed next to each other isn't it? please clarify

Comment: yes, so for i*n1 +j, we scan the correct way, thank you !!!

Comment: you are god for me!